# Data Entry on Hidden Elements with Selenium (Python 2.7) - Elements not visible

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script to login to my bank account, using Selenium and Python 2.7.  Historically, it worked, however it is now throwing an ElementNotVisibleException exception. This is my code:

```
import time
import os 
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

user_id = raw_input('Enter your account number')
password = raw_input('Enter your password')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

def regular():

    site = driver.get('https://www.meridiancu.ca/');

    enter_user_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="memberNo"]').send_keys(user_id)

regular()
```

And here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Programming\Python Files\Monthly\Banking.py", line 50, in <module>
    regular()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Programming\Python Files\Monthly\Banking.py", line 19, in regular
    enter_user_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="memberNo"]').send_keys(user_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 349, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible**
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

The exception is being thrown at `enter_user_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="memberNo"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tried to identify the **Member Number/User ID** field with `xpath` as **`//*[@id="memberNo"]`**, this `xpath` exactly matches **5** elements in the `HTML`. So we need to construct an unique `css` or `xpath` which will uniquely identify the **Member Number/User ID** field as follows :

- **`xpath`**

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='homepage-banner-block-grx desktop']//input[@id='memberNo' and @type='text']").send_keys(user_id)
  ```
- **`css_selector`**

  ```
  driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.homepage-banner-block-grx.desktop input#memberNo[type=text]").send_keys(user_id)
  ```

**Note** :

- While constructing the `xpath` ensure we need to avoid the field **Member Number/User ID** in  `START TO JUMP CONTENT LINK` section, `mobile nav` section and with `mobile-buttons` class.
- Also we need to ensure that the `xpath` identifies the **text** field not any *hidden* field.
- Finally, if you are invoking `send_keys(user_id)` method on an element it returns **void**

Comment: This site changes design as the site is resized. This locator will only work when the site is in "desktop mode". If the browser is smaller because it's not maximized or mobile/tablet testing is done, this won't find the visible element. It always finds the element in the desktop version.

Comment: What exactly you mean by `If the browser is smaller because it's not maximized`? Do your `real time Application's test execution` ever executes with **browser is smaller** and **not maximized** ? What is **driver.manage().window().maximize();** for? I feel you are still misguiding not only OP but the entire StackOverflow community.

Comment: OP isn't using `maximize()` in the code he provided and you didn't specify that it is required to find the element with the locator you provided. If you don't specify `maximize()`, the browser is not going to maximize itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm primarily familiar with C#, so you may need to spend a second finding the exact method translations, but here's what I'd suggest:

First, see if you are finding an element that is not actually what you intended (there should be an element.Highlight() method, or if that doesn't work element.Location)

Then, see if it has any children masking it (and if it does click them instead)

If that doesn't work, [use action chains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) to move your mouse to the location of the element and click on it.

Feel free to ask me if you need help implementing this

Answer (score 0):

Because your xpath can match 5 elements and the first element is hidden, that's why report 'ElementNotVisiableException'.

Why your script worked before, but now. I think the website re-designed, now it support responsive to adapt difference browser size. There are 5 inputbox for UserID for different browser size.

Change to

```
enter_user_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.desktop input[name="memberNo"]').send_keys(user_id)
```

Please test the css selector: `div.desktop input[name="memberNo"]` in browser DevTool manually firstly to confirm it can work under your browser size. If it can't work, please change the css selector by youself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there are 5 `INPUT` tags, each with the id `memberNo`, but only one is visible. What I have done in the past in a scenario like this is to get the collection of elements that match that locator and filter the list down to only those that are visible. You should end up with only one element in the list, the one you want. That should look something like

```
memberNos = filter(lambda e: e.is_displayed(), driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#memberNo"))
memberNos[0].send_keys(user_id)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Member Number/User ID field can be found by a simple `find_element_by_xpath()` or `find_element_by_css_selector()` where as you went for a complicated way to create a list through `find_elements_by_css_selector()`. You mentioned about `5 INPUT tags`. Though you have considered the `displayed()` elements only still the first element of the list won't be the expected one as you haven't taken into account the `sign-in-mobile` class.

Comment: It does answer the question if you understood it. The problem is that there are 5 inputs that all have the same ID on the page but only one of them will be visible at any given time. As the site size changes, the element that is displayed changes. This approach is flexible yet still simple and finds only the displayed input and will do so no matter the size/mode of the site. The first line gets all 5 inputs and filters them down to only the one that is displayed. The second line just gets the first (and only) element in the list and sends the text to it.

Comment: I have explained all the steps you have considered which `doesn't` seems to be anywhere near to OP's requirement.

Comment: His requirement is to find the element. I have provided a way to do that no matter the size of the site or device he plans to use in the future so that it's flexible and futureproof. I've done it in two lines where you've done yours in one but it will only ever find the element on the desktop site.